# How to add a countdown timer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had already place the asp:timer inside my javascript, but I have no idea how it work. Let say it count down 60 minutes, what should I write in code behind.

Comment: Did you try _anything_?

Comment: Are users really going to be on that one page for 60 minutes?

Comment: @user3115280.. Please share the code of what you have tried. It need not be the realtime code, but a sample one is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example at the bottom of the msdn documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

The tick callback will be called serverside, however. You will have to get the page to reload to access any changes that you make in the timer's callback.